# Long list item creates unwanted indent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This problem is difficult to describe so i created a jsfiddle. You can see that the final item in the menu sticks out to the right, unlike the other menu items. This happens with other menu items if they take up more than one line.

http://jsfiddle.net/V82un/

Comment: That's word-wrapping. Your text doesn't fit in the space provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `<a>` element is `display: inline;` by default, so the border only appears at the end of the second line. Change `#sidebar_all_pages a` to `display: block` and the problem is solved. It unmasks another one though: The negative margin on `#sidebar_all_pages li` is too big. Reduce it to `-10px` to solve that one.

Comment: That works great, thanks. I only thought of inspecting the `li` item, i hadn't considered the `a` element.

Answer (score 0):

`text-align: right` means the text is, well, right-aligned. This means thet the right edge of everey line of text will stick to the right inner edge of its container.

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping the text in a span with following css rule:

```
display:inline-block;
max-width:190px;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5XuTV/)